# Defining an expression or code with lookup RS

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to migrate a CR report to RS.

I have two Methods, that are basically two queries, one is called "Products" the other one is called "Volume".

Both these datasets have a field called ID.
The idea is to count ProductsID = VolumeID. Can I use a lookup as an expression inside RS that counts when lookup is not equal to Nothing? Or I have to do a code to do that?

EDIT:
Let me add more information.
Crystal Report is managing these in the Data Layer of the web app like this:

```
                DataRow drVol = vols.Rows.Find(new Object[] { id, idEzd });
                if (drVol != null)
                {
                    if (drVol["Volume"] != System.DBNull.Value)
                        cRow.Volume = (isNormalReport ? Convert.ToDecimal(drVol["Volume"]) : Convert.ToDecimal(drVol["Volume"]));
                    else
                        cRow.Volume = 0;

                    dset.Compradores.Rows.Add(cRow);
                }
```

So in this case I verified that RS is giving me an X amount of rows while CR is giving me another amount of rows.

The Idea is to duplicate this on an expression or VB code inside RS.
As you can see, we have to filter the `drVol != null`, RS is bringing all the rows.

I know a Lookup function can be used in this case as:

```
Lookup(Fields!id.Value & Fields!idEzd.Value, Fields!id.Value & Fields!idEzd.Value,Fields!Givemethisfield.Value,"Dataset")
```

But can I use this Lookup expression inside a code to count?
The counter should be something like this (Then I should add the lookup or an if that equals that vlookup, can the code see the two datasets?):

```
Dim count=0 as integer
Public Function Counter() as Integer

count = count + 1
return count

End Function

Public Function GetCounter () as integer

return count

End Function
```

Then create a Calculated Field for example "Counter" with the expression

```
=Code.Counter()
```

And then make the sum of that calculated field:

```
=Sum(Fields!Counter.Value)
```

But is not working, not even the counter, is giving me 0.

Sorry if I made a mistake in the Visual Basic code, I don't program in Visual.

EDIT2:
I saw some workaround on MSDN, something like:

```
Lookup(Fields!id.Value & Fields!idEzd.Value, Fields!id.Value & Fields!idEzd.Value,Fields!Givemethisfield.Value,"Dataset").Lenght
```

It makes sense as a lookup is an Array.

The problem is, either if I choose one scope or the other, I still have the problem that some fields can't be seen for example if the fields `id` and `idezd` are on Dataset1 and `Givemethisfield` is on Dataset2, it will either not see the id,idEzd or Givemethisfield.